# Question about spin-$½$ particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, experimental-physics, wavefunction, quantum-spin

Spin-½ particles needs to rotate 720º to return to its original state. If you rotate it 360º, its state will become opposite, for example $\left| ↑ \right>$ to $-\left| ↑ \right>$. This is my understanding of it.

But I have some questions: Can we actually "rotate" a particle? How? If we can, how is $\left| ↑ \right>$ different from $-\left| ↑ \right>$ ?

I found that Wikipedia says that is detectable with interference experiments, but can spin states interference with each other?

Comment: For an electron you could put it in a magnetic field that is perpendicular to the initial spin of the electron, that would make the state rotate between up and down.